# swift google maps GMSCircle and GMSMarker positions not same

Tags: ios, swift

I create a GMSCircle and a GMSMarker. They both use the *same* coordinates yet they are not positioned at the same spot on the map. The bottom of the GMSMarker is positioned about the middle of the GMSCircle.

```
let circ = GMSCircle(position: markerCoord, radius: 10.0)    
let gMarker: GMSMarker = GMSMarker(position: markerCoord)
```

GMSMarker does not use anchor.

Photo to show the difference. The marker is created from a label. They both use the same color. The goal is to have the marker sit at the same position of the circle inline with the line like the circle does and remove the circle.

[image]

Anyone have an idea of why?

Comment: The "anchor" of a marker is of course its bottom (the tip). And the "anchor" of the circle is intuitively the centre. I don't think you can change these things. In the computer's mind, they are at the same position. What is _your_ definition of "the same position"?

Comment: I was thinking/hoping they would both be drawn at the center. Google docs don't say where the GMSCircle anchor is

Comment: Hi, a screenshot would help.

Comment: A GMSMarker is used to mark a position, so obviously the anchor point is at the tip. Don't you think?

Comment: @Glenn picture added.

Comment: @Sweeper the docs don't say anything about the anchor point being the tip so I don't  what "tip" you are talking about